# Itune connect alpha/beta testing Test vs Production EndPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have a test and production version of an iOS app. They both pointed to different server endpoints.

My test version of the app have different bundle id than the production version.
For example:

```
Test: com.xiaowoo.someapptest    
Prod: com.xiaowoo.someappprod
```

With the new ituneconnect alpha/beta testing, I wont be able to send the two version to my testers easily like I used to do using the testflightapp because I only have 1 app in my ituneconnect(the production version). This 1 app's bundle id is my iOS production bundle id, meaning it only allows me to send out my production app for test.

Now thinking, does this mean I need to create a new app(the test version) in ituneconnect and also create new distribution provisioning profile for my test app? in order to test out my test iOS app?

Is there any other way to send out both the test and production ios builds through ituneconnect?

thanks, would appreciate any suggestions, and comments.

Comment: Is it critical that your beta/production apps have different bundle ids?

Comment: Yes. The original problem is my testers are confused between the builds I sent him/her. They do not know which is test and production. So i created two different bundle id and different app icons.